# How can I call a function after a time delay in the main thread in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a UIControl that calls a function after 0.5 seconds depending on how many times the user presses it.
(Eg 1 press calls f1(), 2 presses calls f2(), 3 presses calls f3())

So basically I need to set a timer when a user presses the Control. If the Control is not pressed for 0.5 seconds then create a dialog. I have tried using a DispatchQueue, but when it gets to the point of making the dialog, it takes several seconds. I think it is because it is being called concurrently instead of on the main thread (apologies if poor terminology).

```
self.operationQueue.cancelAllOperations() //To cancel previous queues
self.mainAsyncQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "bubblePressed" + String(describing: DispatchTime.now()), qos: DispatchQoS.default, attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent)

let time = DispatchTime.now()
self.currentTime = time

self.mainAsyncQueue!.asyncAfter(deadline: time + 0.5){
  guard self.currentTime == time else {
    return
  }

  let tempOperation = BlockOperation(block:{
    self.displayDialog()
  })
  self.operationQueue.addOperation(tempOperation)
}
```

`operationQueue` and `mainAsycQueue` are defined in `viewDidLoad` as

```
self.currentTime = DispatchTime.now()
self.operationQueue = OperationQueue()
```

How can I call my function `displayDialog()` in the main thread so that it loads faster?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to update the UI on a thread other than the main thread. You don't need any operation queues nor do you need to create that `mainAsyncQueue`. For this code, all you need is the main queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it needs to be anywhere near that complicated.   You can just use a `Timer`;

```
class MyClass: UIViewController {

    var tapCount = 0
    var tapTimer: Timer?

    @IBAction tapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if tapCount < 3 {
            tapCount += 1
            tapTimer?.invalidate()
            tapTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false, block: { (timer) in
                switch (self.tapCount) {
                    case 1:
                      self.f1()
                    case 2:
                      self.f2()
                    case 3:
                      self.f3()
                    default:
                      // Hmm, shouldn't happen
                }
                self.tapCount = 0
            })
    }
}
```

The timer will be scheduled on the main queue by default, so there is no need to dispatch anything on the main queue specifically

Comment: Thanks :) 

`timer.invalidate` is what I needed to prevent the `f1` `f2` `f3` functions being called multiple times!

Comment: This answer help to me, Thx

Answer (score 5):

Based on the question title, answer is:

```
let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
   //update UI here
   self.displayDialog()
}
```

or

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { 
   self.displayDialog()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below func, it executes the func in the main thread and no other action will perform during this execution.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.displayDialog()                
}
```

Comment: Yep, but if the OP merely did the initial `asyncAfter` to the main queue like adev suggested, then this inner `async` call is not needed at all.